# Error Processing Request: dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 and today I just edited my `local.xml` in `app/etc/local.xml`. I just added some lines like:

```
<cache>
    <backend><![CDATA[memcached]]></backend>
    <fast_backend><![CDATA[memcached]]></fast_backend>
    <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
    <fast_backend_options>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host>127.0.0.1</host>
                <port>11211</port>
                <persistent>1</persistent>
             </server>
        </servers>
    </fast_backend_options>
    <prefix><![CDATA[MAGE_]]></prefix>
</cache>
```

before i did that i backup my `local.xml` file . When i got a error i uploaded the backup. But it gives me the same error. Please tell me how to fix this.

Error image -

[image: Error Image]

The file i got from error log record. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:65:"dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:1637:
"#0 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(32312): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(24213): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#2 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(24245): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#3 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#4 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(5882): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#5 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(5887): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(21091): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(20949): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#8 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/includes/src/__default.php(20832): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#9 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/elawonen_nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Then, I deleted all the files in var/cache. Now, The first page of the website works fine but the product page aren't loading also the backend login page isn't loading. I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Do you have compilation enabled on your site?

Comment: What was the error you got?

Comment: Yes, i have compilation enabled. The error you can find here - http://imgur.com/dvBo1iX

Comment: Follow this link :- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80629/getting-this-error-message-dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-ada

Comment: Please check the updated problem.

Comment: How did you backup `local.xml`? Does it still end in `.xml`? If so, Magento will still load it, causing grief as Magento tries to merge every file ending in `.xml` in `app/etc/`

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the compilation in magento and clear cache then work you store again

here is information in details :

There are two ways in which this can be done:

1. Via Magento admin

Navigate to System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button
Navigate to System > Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button.

2. Via SFTP, by editing the `includes/config.php` file

To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php. At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

3. Via SSH

   `php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable`

   `php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear`

Check the status:

```
# php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Not Compiled
Collected Files Count:    0
Compiled Scopes Count:    0

Clear the cache:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
```

If you are a Create Hosting customer on the Magento Hosting Plan, feel free to submit a support ticket and we can take care of this issue for you.